# How to pass these 2 parameters to controller action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have 2 actions methods, one them works as "Get" method but shows a list and just gets 1 value from user. The other updates the database with the value received. However, it seems like I'm not passing this value to the 2nd controller as I see it to be `null` when debugging code. 
Can anyone help find my mistake ?

The action methods :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult AvaliaAluno()
    {
        var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (User.IsInRole("Docentes") || User.IsInRole("Comissao"))
        {
            Docente d = db.Docentes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user);

            var vm = new ViewModels
            {
                Propostas = db.Propostas.Where(x => x.DocenteId == d.DocenteId).ToList(),
                Alunos = db.Alunos.ToList(),
                Candidaturas = db.Candidaturas.ToList()
            };
            return View(vm);
        }

        if (User.IsInRole("Empresas"))
        {
            Empresa d = db.Empresas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user);

            var vm = new ViewModels
            {
                Propostas = db.Propostas.Where(x => x.EmpresaId == d.EmpresaId).ToList(),
                Alunos = db.Alunos.ToList(),
                Candidaturas = db.Candidaturas.ToList()
            };
            return View(vm);
        }
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ConfirmaAvaliacao(int id, decimal? avaliacao)
    {
        Candidatura c = db.Candidaturas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CandidaturaId == id);
        Proposta p = db.Propostas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PropostaId == c.PropostaId);
        if (User.IsInRole("Docentes") || User.IsInRole("Comissao"))
        { 
            p.AvaliacaoDocenteAluno = avaliacao;
            return RedirectToAction("AvaliaAluno");
        }

        if (User.IsInRole("Empresas"))
        {
            p.AvaliacaoEmpresaALuno = avaliacao;
            return RedirectToAction("AvaliaAluno");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

and the view:

```
@model DEIS_ISEC.Models.ViewModels

<h3>Alunos Orientados por si</h3>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        Nome do Aluno
    </th>
    <th>
        Número do Aluno
    </th>
    <th>
        Ramo Inscrito
    </th>
    <th>
        Titulo da Proposta
    </th>
    <th>
        Ramo da Proposta
    </th>
    <th>
        Data de Início
    </th>
    <th>
        Data de Fim
    </th>

    <th>
        Avaliar
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Propostas)
{
    <tr>
        @foreach (var c in Model.Candidaturas)
        {
            if (c.PropostaId == item.PropostaId)
            {
                foreach (var a in Model.Alunos)
                {
                    if (a.AlunoId == c.AlunoId)
                    {
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => a.Nome) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => a.Apelido)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => a.NumeroAluno)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => a.Ramo)
                        </td>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ramo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataInicio)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataFim)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.AvaliacaoDocenteAluno, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:50% !important; min-width:50px;" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.AvaliacaoDocenteAluno, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Guardar", "ConfirmaAvaliacao", new { id = item.CandidaturaId, avaliacao = item.AvaliacaoDocenteAluno }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-md" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I believe that the moment when i get the input from user here :

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.AvaliacaoDocenteAluno, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:50% !important; min-width:50px;" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.AvaliacaoDocenteAluno, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

something unexpected happens.

Comment: You should `modelItem => modelItem.AvaliacaoDocenteAluno` and `modelItem => modelItem.AvaliacaoDocenteAluno`, no?

Comment: Why do you have an editor (EditorFor) at all?  I don't see a submit button anywhere.

Comment: I have an editor so i can get input from user. Html.action link has a "submit button".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [ASP.NET MVC 4 Helpers, Forms and Validation > Exercise 3: Creating the Edit View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers-forms-and-validation#exercise-3-creating-the-edit-view) on how to implement an **Edit** mechanism with **ASP.Net MVC**.

In general, I recommend you go over the complete example in the link, as it covers many of the subjects required for building an **ASP.Net MVC** application.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I dont want to edit 1 entire model. I just want to get value for 1 property of the model.

Comment: You can still use that method to update that single field and you can use DisplayFor for the fields you don't want to edit

Comment: ok, looks good. I just thought it wouldnt be good(visually) to create an entire edit view just to display 1 field.